# CvGet2D is included in which library?

Tags: c++, opencv

How can I know from OpenCV features cvGet2D is included in which library of OpenCV?

Comment: @berak
OK, if you say that, then, suggest another alternative for c++, can you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is defined in core_c.h file.